# Can I use the USB port of MacBook Air 2016 to connect with HDMI instead of using the Thunderbolt port?

Tags: thunderbolt, hdmi

Am trying to connect my MacBook Air 2016 to the TV via HDMI instead of using the Thunderbolt port cable to HDMI. Can I use one of the USB ports to connect to HDMI? The reason I asked is that I found Thunderbolt to HDMI cables are not that commonly found in the market, not in the shops I visited at least, and thought might be USB to HDMI would be easier to get.

Comment: Pre-USB-C MacBook Air models seem to support video output over Mini DisplayPort and Thunderbolt only (see https://support.apple.com/kb/SP753), so a USB-A-to-HDMI adapter won't work with your MacBook (in fact, looking at the description of several products online, I haven't found any that explicitely supports macOS). You could buy a Mini DisplayPort-to-HDMI adapter instead, the ones I've checked support macOS.

Comment: Dennus: According to [everyman.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/index-macbook-air.html), Apple did not make any MacBook Air models in 2016. Are you sure about your model and year?

Comment: Frankly, m not sure about the model as the Macbook Air I mentioned is my daughter who bought that in Aug 2016 and she told me there's not any HDMI output but only a thunderbolt port.

Comment: In addition, is Mini Display Port equivalent to Thunderbolt port? I saw Mini Display Port to HDMI adapters in shops around here but can't find any thunderbolt port to HDMI adaptors.